# Want to Remove Icon from Language Selection Screen

Tags: install4j

I have a Requirement to Remove Icon shown in Language selection as shown below.

How Can I achieve this?

[image]

I want replace custom image in language selection, marked red below.

I tried to use a custom icon in the "Executable icon" property of the installer. It is changing only the screen title window ICON not screen body Image. However screen body is still showing the default image not custom image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the icon, but if you specify a custom icon in the "Executable icon" property of the installer and include an image that has a size of 32x32, that icon will be shown instead.