# Want to Replace Icon in Language Selection Screen

Tags: install4j

Initially I wanted to Remove Icon From Language Selection screen body not Title window.
As install4j does not support to remove image from language selection screen now i want to replace default image shown in Language selection marked red in attached Image with Custom image.

I tried to use a custom icon in the "Executable icon" property of the installer. It is changing only the title ICON not screen body Image. However screen body is still showing the default image not custom image

[image]

How Can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to Remove Icon from Language Selection Screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35729212/want-to-remove-icon-from-language-selection-screen)

Comment: Please don't ask a new question if there is a problem with an answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35729212/want-to-remove-icon-from-language-selection-screen   answer for this was correct. Now I have updated my requirement.